# Saved google maps: access from iPhone?

Tags: google-maps, iphone

Is there a way from the iphone to get to maps that I've saved in google maps at the regular site?

Comment: Without jail-breaking the phone I am not sure , also what level of detail (zoom) are you looking at ? I used to had an application on my old Sony K810i and it requires lots of dirty work (downloading large images and folders)

Comment: Here's a workaround Quora answer I found... http://qr.ae/p4qwV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“My Maps” are now available on the mobile version of Google maps.

1. In Safari on your iPhone go to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com).
2. Click on the top right icon on the toolbar (a circle with a small triangle pointing down).
3. Click on “My Maps”

I have to say that the interface didn't respond very well for me when I tried, it was nearly impossible to properly zoom in to some points of interest. But well, at least it's there and hopefully will get better over time.

Comment: Pretty sad that 4 years later (an eternity for mobile apps), still no official Google My Maps on native iPhone app.

Answer (score 5):

1. In safari go to **maps.google.com**
2. Tap the bottom left icon on the map (it looks like a list).
   *An alternative to this step is to scroll down on the page before the map has fully loaded.*
3. Click **classic** on the bottom of the page.
4. You are now in the desktop version of the site. The map will still allow you to pan and zoom using the normal gestures, the only problem is panning and zooming on the page itself is very difficult.
5. Click **sign in** on the top right of the page if you aren't already signed in.
6. Click on **My Maps** on the top left.

As I mentioned earlier, panning and zooming on the white part of the page is very difficult. For me it only works 25% of the time. Here are some tips you can try:

- When using a multi-finger gesture such as zoom, make sure both fingers touch the screen at the same time.
- Make sure the gesture is performed on the white area of the page (not on the map). Gesture perfomed on the map will pan or zoom only the map portion.
- Panning doesn't work. The only way to successfully pan is to use zooming and move the zoomed content.
- Make sure the fingers are far enough apart to be recognized as two fingers and not one large one.

Comment: My maps are now available directly on the mobile version of Google maps. See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/saved-google-maps-access-from-iphone/15235#15235).

Answer (score 3):

There are other options:

You can try using my service: http://my-maps.appspot.com/. 
It will open your "my maps" on the native Maps application.

There are also a couple of native applications on the app store.

Comment: Apparently this method is no longer working because of a change on Google's APIs, but they do offer [a workaround](http://my-maps.appspot.com/old). In any case, this shows only locations in saved maps (which could be very useful!), but not other features such as routes.

Answer (score -1):

Download the Google Earth app and log in, from there you can see your 'my maps'.

Comment: Where exactly is that? Perhaps you can add a screenshot? Please read the [faq].